# How to get exact region of a path on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, path, region

I'm using this to get a paths region:

```
 RectF rectF = new RectF();
 Path currentPath = getCurrentPath();
 currentPath.computeBounds(rectF, true);
 Region region = new Region();
```

This gives me a rect like this:

[image]

The green rect is the region that I can get from circle.

I want to move the red circle by dragging so I need its exact boundaries not this rect.

The circle can be moveable from center of it with this method but I don't want it. I want it to be moveable just from its exact red points.

How can I determine exact boundaries?

Answer (score 1):

I just solve this problem by using two Regions. Here is the example code:

First, get the big circle Region as clickableRegion:

```
Region clickableRegion = new Region(); 
RectF rectF = new RectF();
// bigCirclePath is the red ring
Path bigCirclePath = getBigCirclePath();
bigCirclePath.computeBounds(rectF, true);
Rect rect = new Rect((int)rectF.left, (int)rectF.top, (int)rectF.right, (int)rectF.bottom);
// this will get the circle Region
clickableRegion.setPath(bigCirclePath, new Region(rect));
```

Then, use similar code to get the small circle Region as disClickableRegion. The small circle should has the same center with your bigCircle.

Define a `contains` function;

```
public boolean conatins(Point p) { 
    if(disClickableRegion.contains(p.x, p.y)) {
        return false;
    }

    return clickableRegion.contains(p.x, p.y);
}
```